# Excel's CHIDIST function in MATLAB

Tags: chi-squared-test, matlab, excel, chi-squared-distribution

How to reproduce MS Excel's [CHIDIST](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/chidist-HP005209010.aspx) function in MATLAB?

> Returns the one-tailed probability of the chi-squared distribution. The χ2 distribution is associated with a χ2 test. Use the χ2 test to compare observed and expected values. For example, a genetic experiment might hypothesize that the next generation of plants will exhibit a certain set of colors. By comparing the observed results with the expected ones, you can decide whether your original hypothesis is valid.
>
> Syntax
>
> CHIDIST(x,degrees_freedom)
>
> X     is the value at which you want
> to evaluate the distribution.
>
> Degrees_freedom     is the number of
> degrees of freedom.

So, if I have column of numbers as `x` and use the formula like `=CHIDIST(A1:A60,3)`, it returns 1 number.

I have tried to follow two advices from [this thread](http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/241781), but I always get a vector of numbers, not one number.

Comment: CHIDIST, like many Excel functions, works when applied to arrays: it threads over the array in this case and returns one value for each of the 60 cells in the range a1:a60.  (Tested with Excel 2002.)  *If you do not enter it as an array function,* the value you are getting is the first value: in this case, it will equal `CHIDIST(A1, 3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're using the correct function?  CHIDIST in excel takes a single number, not an array.  `chidist(a1:a60,3)` doesn't make sense in this case.

Using the code from the MATLAB thread you mentioned, the following are equivalent:

```
CHIDIST(x,df) (in Excel)
1-chi2cdf(x,df) (in MATLAB)
```

Comment: You are right. It's my mistake in the formula understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `CHIDIST` in matlab would be using `chi2cdf` with the argument `'upper'`. This returns the complement of chi2 cdf at the value of the chi square statistic.

```
chi2cdf(x,df,'upper')
```